# Finding a variable name given its numerical value

Tags: variable-definitions

If I set up

```
a = 1
```

Is there any command to get `"a"` by typing value `1`?

Another example.

If

```
x = 3

y = 7

z = 6
```

then, Can I get `'xyz'` by typing something like `{3,7,6}`?

Comment: What if you had typed `x = 3; y = 7; z = 3;`, what would you expect to get back by then typing `{3,7}`?

Comment: @S.Lee does my answer fit your needs?

Answer (score 13):

```
a = 1;

Select[Names["Global`*"], Symbol[#] == 1 &]
```

> ```
> {"a"}
> ```

Notice it may not be robust if you have a habit of writing procedures with `OwnValues`, e.g.: `c := NotebookClose @ EvaluationNotebook[]` etc.

```
ClearAll[a]
a := Echo["this is only echo but it may be something more damaging"];
b = 1;

Select[Names["Global`*"], Symbol[#] == 1 &]
```

> ```
> >> this is only echo but it may be something more damaging
>
> {"b"}
> ```

To avoid this you can scan `OwnValues` instead of using `Symbol`/`ToExpression`:

```
Select[
  Names["Global`*"]
, ToExpression[
    #
  , StandardForm
  , Function[sym, MemberQ[OwnValues[sym], _ :> 1], HoldFirst]
  ] &
]
```

> ```
> {"b"}
> ```